# When labelling VCS from TeamCity, how can I make externals be pinned to a specific revision

Tags: svn, teamcity, svn-externals

(I can't understand why SVN even lets you create a tag with externals that point to HEAD, but be that as it may...)
I've finally managed to get automatic build labelling working, and I see my tags created in SVN on successful builds, but the externals in that tag still point at HEAD. Is there a way to get it to pin to the current revision, or do I have to do that manually on trunk beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that tagging in Subversion does not automatically pin your externals to a specific revision. So yes, you need to adjust your externals to point to a specific revisions then create a tag.

You may write a tagging / release script that automatically does this task and then creates a new tag.